# Python regex pattern without curly braces

Tags: python, regex

How can I return a string that hasn't curly braces on it?
Example, in bellow code I want pattern.group(3) matches only code with no curly braces.

```
pattern = re.search('(.*)#ifdef (.*?)if(.*?)#endif(.*?){(.*?)}(.*)',codigo,re.DOTALL)
```

So

```
#ifdef expression_1
  if (condition_1)
#endif
{
  //lines of code
}
```

is suposed to match, and

```
#ifdef SIZE == 1                
         if(x == 2){


            //lines of code 2


        }
#endif
```

not.

Comment: Why don't you do a check on returned groups?

Answer (score 0):

I would just surround the whole curly braces section in a non-capturing group and make it optional.  That way you'll still get a regex match object back with the other groups filled.

```
'(.*)#ifdef (.*?)if(.*?)#endif(.*?)(?:{(.*?)})?(.*)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was looking for something like that

```
re.search('(.*)#ifdef (.*?)if([^{]*?)#endif(.*?){(.*?)}(.*)',codigo,re.DOTALL)
```

So, I garantee that there isn't any { in group(3).